# How to drive multiple object types onto a net in AMS?

Tags: system-verilog

In the QuestaSIM User's Manual version 10.5a it is stated on page 336:

> In the most recent SystemVerilog standard (Std IEEE 1800-2012), two important concepts were established:
>
> User-Defined Nettype (UDN) — UDN allows a definition of a net type
>   that can carry arbitrarily complex data using a built-in type (such as
>   real) or a user-defined type (such as struct). Consequently, UDN is a
>   generalization of the wreal net type from Verilog-AMS. In order to
>   allow connectivity of models that rely on UDNs, a more generic
>   connectivity mechanism is needed—the interconnect object.

But they really don't specify how the UDN is constructed. The syntax references to 'nettype' and 'interconnect' seem to come close to this description, but neither fulfills it - I can't assign interconnect, and I'm unable to use my own types with nettype. I'm creating a model that needs to drive user defined objects onto a UDN as defined in the spec.

```
module SomeModel(output nettype ObjectContainingProperties outputToInterconnect);

class ObjectContainingProperties;

endclass

ObjectContainingProperties ocp;
assign outputToInterconnect=ocp;

initial begin
    ocp=new();
end

endmodule
```

but I get the error:

```
QuestaSim-64 vlog 10.5a Compiler 2016.04 Apr  4 2016
Start time: 18:55:05 on Dec 19,2016
vlog -ams -wireasinterconnect SomeModel.sv 
-- Compiling module SomeModel
** Error: (vlog-13069) SomeModel.sv(11): near "nettype": syntax error, unexpected nettype, expecting IDENTIFIER.
```

How do I create and attach an object to a UDN - what is the syntax? Or how do I reliably drive objects of different types onto a net?

Comment: The text you are quoting is not from the IEEE 1800-2012 standard. Have you looked at the example in section _6.6.7 User-defined nettypes_?

Comment: I accidentally cropped the top of the question while editing. Not sure it deserves a downvote for that, I corrected it.

Comment: do yo have the IEEE 1800-2012 manual?

Comment: Yes, I fully understand the section you reference 6.6.7 suggests that nettype T can assign types of T. What I'm looking for is a method using 6.6.8, interconnect, where I can drive multiple generically typed nets in the same module. Or is this impossible, and decomposition and partitioning needs to occur to drive the various nettypes onto interconnect on a higher level block?

Comment: I suspect I may need to change the error example for future reference, but when I posted it I was assuming that there was an equivalent to "Object" for nets that is present in other languages. I don't think I quite understand yet. Essentially I have various Voltage/Current/Noise types, and they do not derive from the same parent class. To drive one net through a system is the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User defined nettypes are not part of SystemVerilog's OOP `class` type system. You can only define nettypes that are structures or arrays containing combinations of bits or real numbers. Classes are only used to get access to parameterized functions. (See 13.8 Parameterized tasks and functions).

You can only drive similar types onto a net. If you look at the prototype of a resolution function(from section 6.6.7)

```
function automatic T Tsum (input T driver[]);
```

You see that the function has one input argument that is an array. That will be populated with the values from all the drivers on the net - they must all be the same type.

The `interconnect` construct is just a conduit for a connection. It will assume the type of what ever it is connected to, and you will not be able to connect signals with different nettypes to the same `interconnect`

Comment: Is it fair to say that if I subclass everything from T, that my objects will able to be applied without issue? So essentially creating a base NetTypeObject from which all is inherited from? I'm assuming this works with multiple drivers using 'with' as resolution.

Comment: Except that T cannot be a class type.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like driving a net with user defined types isn't supported. To get around this, if I had a singleton at the top, and drove values on the net, the value on the net could be a lookup key for an object? Does that seem fair?

Comment: If structs aren't good enough, you could make a string nettype which is essentially a serialization of any number of classes, then parse/instantiate then all as needed in the resolution function before serializing it back to a string.